# Cloud Armor with GKE to restrict access to Ingress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-armor

We are implementing Cloud Armor policies with GKE to restrict access to Ingress and allow only IP ranges whitelisted in armor policies.
Steps followed:

1. Created a cloud armor policy to whitelist certain ranges and deny
   all the other.
2. Created a BackendConfig with security policy
   referencing armor policy.
3. Added backendconfig as annotation to k8s
   service.

Added `Security admin` to Node Service Account and Kubernetes Engine Service Agent

Any help is appreciated, TIA!

`Error syncing to GCP: error running backend syncing routine: failed to set security policy from "" to "armor-policy-name" for backend service backend-service-name (namespace/serverice-name:&ServiceBackendPort{Name:,Number:80,}): googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource': '{ "securityPolicy": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/gcp_project_name/global/s...'. deny action is only supported for TCP and SSL load balancers., invalid`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can only use the `deny` action with TCP or SSL load balancers.  Since you are attaching the policy to Ingress, you need to use `deny-403`, `deny-404` or `deny-502` as the action in your rule.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/security-policies/rules/create#--action